# Which iOS devices do I have to test with?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

I have iPod touch 4th.
And I'm developing iPhone app with it.
I use ARC. So target iOS is iOS5.0 or later.

I will buy iPhone 4S before releasing the app to test with iPhone 4S.

Is it good idea to buy iPhone 4S and test with it?
And testing with iPod touch 4th and iPhone 4S is enough?

Don't I have to test with iPad or iPhone 4 or 3GS?
(I don't have money to buy them.)

I'm mainly using MPMediaPlayer library and MPMusicPlayer in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most cruel and correct answer is that you have to test with all the devices to make sure everything is fine, but in my opinion is good to test with iPod and iPAd

Answer (score 2):

You should test on as many device as you can. But this could become very difficult and expensieve.

What you could do is find beta testers and let them test the app for you. This way you get the test you app one many device without buying them.

[Test Flight](http://testflightapp.com/) has some great tools to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is advisable that you test your application on all the device with the targeted software version, but most individuals due to limited resources don't do that . So you can outsource this task to other developers on some free lancing websites if you like...  (you can always ask for crash logs from them to check if they actually did it.)TestFlight helps you achieve this.

Comment: thanks! you said that most individuals don't do that. But most individuals do TestFlight? Or most of them doesn't TestFlight, too?

Comment: Serious guys go for TestFlight... now its up to you.. you want to deliver quality product then go for test flight.